# Joining another table with existing junction table

Tags: mysql, orm, relational-database, typeorm

I'm fairly new to database design and could use some guidance with a project I'm working on.

I have three existing tables `accounts`, `users`, and a junction table representing the many-to-many relationship called `accounts_users`.

As you may guess, the `accounts_users` table looks like this:

```
| accountId | userId |
| --------- | ------ |
| 1         | 1      |
| 1         | 2      |
| 2         | 1      |
```

I need to add roles for users, where a user can have a singular role for each account they belong to.

I have created a role table (containing an `id` and `name`), but am looking for guidance on what the next step would be, in order to create a relationship between the `roles` and the `accounts_users` tables.

Should an extra column be added within the `accounts_users` table, containing the `roleId` or should there be another junction table added?

Thank you!

Comment: I would add a role column(s) to the junction table with a foreign  key to a roles table which contains role enrichment data (eg description). You might also consider if roles time expire (eg temporary power of attorney)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is completely fine to store additional data in your junction table. You could use different approaches however, depending on the real meaning of your "role" entity.

- If each account-user pair have its unique role associated (1:1 relationship), you could create the `name` column directly in the `accounts_users` table.
- If one single role is shared between multiple account-user pairs (1:N relationship), you should use separate `roles` table and connect the tables by adding `roleId` foreign key into `accounts_users` table (just as you have written yourself).

The second solution is also suitable when the role entity bears big amount of information with it (multiple columns, not only `name`), so it's undesirable to mess the junction table with unrelated and possibly unneeded data.

Comment: The second bullet point is what I had in mind, so I'll go that route. Thank you so much!